# node user model is vomitting

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I am trying to get my hands dirty with making node api following this tutorial

https://scotch.io/tutorials/authenticate-a-node-js-api-with-json-web-tokens

problem is that when I execute

```
$ nodejs server.js
```

I get this error

```
{ [Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
{ [Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
{ [Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
{ [Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version

module.js:340
    throw err;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module './sou/models/user'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/sou/server.js:12:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3
```

My directory structure is

```
- sou/
----- models/
---------- user.js
- config.js
- package.json
- server.js
```

my server.js is

```
// =======================
// get the packages we need ============
// =======================
var express     = require('express');
var app         = express();
var bodyParser  = require('body-parser');
var morgan      = require('morgan');
var mongoose    = require('mongoose');

var jwt    = require('jsonwebtoken'); // used to create, sign, and verify tokens
var config = require('./config'); // get our config file
var User   = require('./sou/models/user'); // get our mongoose model

// =======================
// configuration =========
// =======================
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080; // used to create, sign, and verify tokens
mongoose.connect(config.database); // connect to database
app.set('superSecret', config.secret); // secret variable

// use body parser so we can get info from POST and/or URL parameters
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// use morgan to log requests to the console
app.use(morgan('dev'));

// =======================
// routes ================
// =======================
// basic route
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Hello! The API is at http://localhost:' + port + '/api');
});

// API ROUTES -------------------
// we'll get to these in a second

// =======================
// start the server ======
// =======================
app.listen(port);
console.log('Magic happens at http://localhost:' + port);
```

my models/user.js

```
// get an instance of mongoose and mongoose.Schema
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// set up a mongoose model and pass it using module.exports
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', new Schema({
    name: String,
    password: String,
    admin: Boolean
}));
```

what am I missing??

thanks

EDIT: Fixing the file path but now getting this error

this

```
{ [Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
{ [Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
{ [Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
{ [Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
Magic happens at http://localhost:8090

/var/www/html/sou/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:228
        process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
                                            ^
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
    at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
    at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:892:19)
```

Comment: Are you doing some pre-processing before you deploy?  `at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/sou/server.js:12:14)` indicates that your `server.js` is inside of `sou`

Comment: Now it would appear you are not connecting to your mongodb.  Are you sure that your connection details are correct and you're running `mongod` if this in local development.

Comment: awesome...can you put that as an answer so I can give you well desrved points!!

Comment: Glad I could help.  I've posted an answer detailing the issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer was mostly resolved in the comments.  Here was the final solution.

First, the project directory was incorrect and the file being required was not where it was supposed to be.  Fixing the require statement fixed this issue.

Second, the server was not able to connect to the mongodb server.  Making sure the mongo server was running, and that the app server had the correct connection details fixed this issue

Hope I helped!